# From test statistics to datasets

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, machine-learning, simulation

Suppose we are given an initial data set $x$. From this dataset, we are able to compute with an appropriate hypothesis test a test statistic (i.e. with a One-Sample T-Test we would get the $t$ statistic).

Now what I am looking for is a way, where by changing the test statistic $t$ to a different value $t_{new}$, generate from it as many new datasets $x^*$, that are still constrained by a descriptive statistic of the original dataset, like the mean $\overline{x}$ or the standard deviation $\sigma_{x}$.

I am currently studying a method using [simulated annealing](https://www.autodeskresearch.com/publications/samestats), which is flexible enough to include as many constraints as possible, but it lacks the property of speed. Two other algorithm classes that I am looking into are an [evolutionary programming](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27643902?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) approach and the one I am most curious about is an adversarial approach using Constrained GANs.

My assumption is that one could train a network for a specific test only, by feeding it a dataset of data together with the output test statistic $t$ and teach the generator to produce data, where the computed test statistic $t_{comput}$ would be relatively close to the inputted test statistic $t_{input}$.

$$ t_{comput} \simeq t_{input} $$

I am curious if any of you have had a similar problem, have any tips for me or would suggest a different approach altogether?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you want or why. So my first
guess may be far too simple.

Suppose we test $H_0:\mu = 30$ against $H_1: \mu \ne 30$ with
$n = 100$ observations from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 35, \sigma = 5).$

In R, I generate data `x` in R statistical software rounded to four decimal places for an example. I show the seed so you can get exactly the same dataset if you wish:

```
set.seed(4318);  x = round(rnorm(100, 35, 5), 4)
a = mean(x);  s = sd(x);  t = (a - 30)*sqrt(100)/s
a;  s;  t
[1] 35.53788
[1] 5.054078
[1] 10.95725
```

[image]

Now I want to constrain the situation to keep 
$a = 35.53788,  t = 10.95725, n = 100$ and hypothetical mean 30. 
If I want a new dataset meeting these constraints, it must also
have sample standard deviation $s = 5.054078.$

To do this; I sample `z` of length 100 from standard normal.

```
set.seed(1234); z = rnorm(100);  a.z = mean(z);  s.z = sd(z)
y = z*s/s.z;  x1 = y - mean(y) + a
a1 = mean(x1);  s1 = sd(x1);  t1 = (a1 - 30)*sqrt(100)/s1
a1;  s1;  t1  
[1] 35.53788
[1] 5.054078
[1] 10.95725
```

Thus, simply by rescaling and shifting `z`, I have gotten a new 
data vector `x1` with *exactly* the same t statistic as `x`. 
If I want it rounded to three places, that does not change 
the t statistic by much.

```
x1.r = round(x1, 3);  t.r = (mean(x1.r) - 30)*sqrt(100)/sd(x1.r)
sd(x1.r);  t.r
[1] 5.054076
[1] 10.95721
```

[image]

This seems too simple, so I await your comment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This helps a lot. My question is now, can I extend this approach to more complex hypothesis tests, and furthermore, can I use this or a similar approach for nonparametric tests (i.e. Kruskal Wallis Test, Man Whitney Test)?

Comment: It may be more difficult to define 'constraints' for nonparametric tests because you don't know what the population distributions are.

Comment: First, why wouldn't one be able to define constraints for nonparametric tests? Couldn't you just constrain the test statistic as before? Second, how could you extend your method to tests like the ANOVA test?

Comment: The word 'nonparametric' is slippery. Sometimes sloppily used for anything that is not normal (leading to such rank-based tests as Wilcoxon, Kruskal-Wallis, Friedman). Sometimes more rigorously used for data with unknown distribution. // Missing the meaning and purpose of 'constraints.' // If you are trying to generate fake data for class exercises, you are swimming against the tide. Amer. Stat. Assn recommends using real data, preferably with documentation and discussion of purpose for collection.

Comment: I am actually working on an application that should work as a sandbox for students learning statistics. Given two datasets (both not normally distributed) we can directly compute a test statistic for the data. Now the user should be able to enter a different value for the test statistic and the program should generate new datasets that would correspond to value of the inputted test statistic, all this while the mean of the first dataset and the standard deviation of the second one are constrained.